# vue pwa webpack axios process.env not escaping url and crashing webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, axios

Hello I am having an issue with setting a base url from an environment variable in config/prod.env.js in the pwa template that is loaded from webpack.
i am setting API_URL to 'http://localhost:3000' where I am running a express js rest api.

source code line where the error is originating from

```
return axios.create({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
  })
```

webpack output from browser

```
return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_axios___default.a.create({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    baseURL: http://localhost:3000/
  });
```

error from the browser console

```
152:40 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1682)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (main.js?1c90:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1207)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1199)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at app.js:725
```

package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: Is this a server side rendered website?

Comment: no this is a client side rendered using webpack to bundle the app

Comment: after some more testing it still occurs when using baseURL: `http://${process.env.API_URL}`. it appears to be a issue with how webpack evaluates variables to strings. just speculating I don't know alot about webpack

Comment: If it had been server side rendered I was gonna suggest `process.env` might not be available to you, but if it's a variable you're using while building with Webpack I'm afraid there's too much that could be wrong since it's based on your own set of scripts for me to give any valuable feedback on. Sorry.

Comment: no problem. I did find a work around using a json config file in the source directory and that did work for me. although if it this is for a large scale app where there is 2 separate endpoints for the api (prod and dev for example) it requires changing there and not depending on what mode is running ether dev or build.